# Sorting Multi-dimension array based on key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array based on a particular key value in a multidimensional array as follows

```
<?php
$country = array(
    array(
        'country' => 'India',
        'visits' => 22,
        'newVisits' => 16,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 72.7),
    array(
        'country' => 'USA',
        'visits' => 30,
        'newVisits' => 15,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 50),
    array(
        'country' => 'Japan',
        'visits' => 25,
        'newVisits' => 15,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 60));
?>
```

I wanna Sort the array in Descending order of the 'visits' key of the array.

Desired Array is

```
<?php
$country = array(
    array(
        'country' => 'USA',
        'visits' => 30,
        'newVisits' => 15,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 50),
    array(
        'country' => 'Japan',
        'visits' => 25,
        'newVisits' => 15,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 60),
    array(
        'country' => 'India',
        'visits' => 22,
        'newVisits' => 16,
        'newVisitsPercent' => 72.7));
?>
```

Tried to search in SO all results were sorting based on the value of the key. Please let me know which function do we need to use.

I looked in to ksort, Multi-sort functions

Comment: [`usort()`](http://php.net/usort) Look at the related column

Comment: by the way this question looks like exactly the same as a couple of minutes ago :) but from user with less profile points than before, I am not trying to guess something or judge, but looks like there are people with multiple accounts

Answer (score 4):

take a look at the documentation of `usort`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 4):

PHP has a builtin function called [usort](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)() which can sort these types of arrays.

Your comparison function could look something like this:

```
function mycmp($a, $b) {
  return intval($a['visits']) - intval($b['visits']);
}
```